# LateInitializationError: Local 'res' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, var

I am making a program for encrypting text relative to a keyword. Initially, the algorithm was written in Python, everything worked correctly. I decided to translate it into a mobile application in Flutter, so I had to rewrite it in Dart.

```
List symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', ';', ':', '-',
'_', ' ', '!', '@', '#', '\$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '\"', '№', '~', '?',
'\\', '/', '|', '[', ']', '{', '}', '`', '\'', '<', '>'];
late dynamic keyWord = ' ';
late dynamic text = ' ';
late dynamic res;
late dynamic a4;
late dynamic m;
late dynamic n;
late dynamic f;
var d = 0;
var k = 0;
var z = 0;
var operation = 0;
var m1 = 0;
var c = 0;

  encode(keyWord, text){
  late dynamic res;
  var l = (text.length) as int;
  for( var i = l ; i >= 1; i-- ){
    if(symbols.contains(text[d])) {
      var f = symbols.indexOf(text[d]);
      a4 = '';
      if(f == 0){
        a4 = '0';
        while(f > 0){
          a4 = (f % 4).toString() + a4.toString();
          f = f ~/ 4;
        }
        a4 = '$a4';
      }
    }
    else{
      a4 += '1123';
    }
    while(a4.length != 4) {
      a4 = '0' + a4;
    }
    for( var j = 4 ; j >= 1; j-- ){
      res += (keyWord[(a4[z]) as int]);
      res.whenComplete((){
        setState(() {});
      });
      z += 1;
    }
    z = 0;
    d += 1;
  }
  return(res);
}
```

The encode function does not work due to `LateInitializationError: Local 'res' has not been initialized.`
The rest of the code works correctly, the `res`
variable was not called anywhere except for this function. Maybe someone faced the same problem or knows how to solve it? I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Why you are using  2times `res`, can change the name and show us the errors, it will be easy to read for us.

Comment: You should probably start programming properly and using types instead of making everything dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception is pretty self-explanatory. You access res in `res += (keyWord[(a4[z]) as int]);`, when it's not yet initialized. You should remove late and do `dynamic res = ''` for example.

P.S. 'res += value' is basically 'res = res + value'. That's why you get the error

P.S.S Why not to use some typing? Your code's res.whenComplete will fail, because it's not a Future. Seems, that you don't use any code completion at all.